# CakePHP Apache The requested URL /posts/view/1 was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, server, routes

I am working through this cakephp tutorial:

part 1: book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html

part 2: book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html

I am part of the way through part 2 and have reached the end of the "Creating Post Views" step however when I try to access the "/posts/view/1" page I get the message that the url requested was not found on server. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFZLM.png)
I am using an apache server on windows and I think it could be due to the way it is set up? Alternatively on the cakephp end do I need to add anything to my [routes file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYy99.png)?

Does anyone have any ideas I should try please?

Thanks!

Comment: Check that your webserver is correctly set up, is other views working? Double-check that your .htaccess files exist. I suggest enabling mod_rewrite in apache.

Comment: Hi thanks I solved it, I have to change an access all in httpd.conf

Comment: Thanks @JazzCat , mod_rewrite did the trick !!